# Is it possible to deploy a Ruby app on a plain clean Passenger setup?

Tags: ruby, apache, .htaccess, passenger

I'm thinking to something really similar on what you can do with mod_php: drop an application in some way inside Apache and making it run with Passenger, without adding *anything* inside httpd.conf (no vhost, nothing except the basic Passenger configuration).
It's something very similar to Wordpress or many other frameworks: just unzip/svn checkout it inside a folder and run it.

I know that it's possible with CGI and FCGI, but I'm wondering if it's also possible to tap in the speed of Passenger.

I've tried fiddling with the Rack instructions on the official website trying to find a specific .htaccess and config.ru configuration, but nothing so far.

I know it's not common, but... is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without configuring a virtual host.

Rails applications are not like PHP files; files on the filesystem do not correspond with URLs. PHP files are placed **within** the `DocumentRoot`, whereas Rails/Rack apps live **outside** the `DocumentRoot`.

It is therefore not possible for Passenger to detect your application's location. You either need to tell it [where it is located](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) in the first place, **or** you need to point your virtual host's `DocumentRoot` to your application's `/public` directory. In that case Passenger will [detect that it is a Rails/Rack app](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_railsautodetect_lt_on_off_gt) and you don't need additional Passenger configuration, but you **do** need a virtual host for each application.

**Update:** The Passenger docs mention that `RailsBaseURI` [is allowed within a .htaccess file](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#RailsBaseURI). Adding this in your document root and creating a symlink from a subdirectory (e.g. `/docroot/yourapp`) to the `/public` dir of your application might then be just what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be completely clear: so I suppose that it isn't possible to do the required configuration inside the .htaccess, right?

Comment: I was confident that it wasn't, but specifying the base URI seems actually possible from an `.htaccess` file; see update.

Comment: <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerAppRoot /path/to/app/root
  RailsEnv staging
  RailsBaseURI /path/to/app/root/public
</IfModule>

Works. :)

Comment: In fact it seems that "PassengerAppRoot /path/to/app/root" in the .htaccess inside the "public" subfolder is enough. I'll do more testing

Comment: To run Sinatra you need both PassengerAppRoot and RackBaseURI.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what is already in your httpd.conf

You can't even run a PHP app without modifying your apache config files on many default apache installs.

Comment: Of course. I'll try to be more clear. :)

I mean configured just with the basic Passenger configuration details, nothing app-specific in the configuration file.

So, I mean, just the three lines specified in the passenger-install-apache2-module installation script to load the library and the obvious AllowOverrides. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dropping config.ru to some directory would do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost possible. If the configuration is done right and apache+mod_rails knows where your application ist you need to change the last modified date of the `/path/to/your/app/tmp/restart.txt`. With ssh access you can do this like this

```
touch /path/to/your/app/tmp/restart.txt
```

more information can be found here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_ruby_on_rails_application

**Update:**

Or you can create the `/path/to/your/app/tmp/always_restart.txt`

more information about this can be found here:
http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_making_the_application_restart_after_each_request

Comment: How does restarting an existing application relate to deploying a new one?

Comment: you can deploy it with the file, and passenger autoloads the new files **UPD:** a ruby application must be restarted after every file change, if you use (F)CGI for your ruby app, it starts a new app server with each request, so it restarts for every request. Passenger spawns 1 or more instances for your app, but doesn't restart for eachh request, it reuses already started processes of your app